# test dataset existence in HDF5/c++ and handle the error

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, dataset, hdf5

I am reading *.hdf5 serie of files with HDF5 library in C++. The files have the same datasets (same `keys`, but different informations), but sometimes a single dataset can miss in a file (e.g. in 100 files I have the dataset `apple`, in 3 files I don't have any `apple` dataset), and in these cases there is the following exception:

```
HDF5-DIAG: Error detected in HDF5 (1.10.7) thread 0:
 #000: H5D.c line 298 in H5Dopen2(): unable to open dataset
   major: Dataset
   minor: Can't open object
 [...]
 #005: H5Gloc.c line 376 in H5G__loc_find_cb(): object 'apple' doesn't exist
   major: Symbol table
   minor: Object not found
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'H5::GroupIException'
```

I would like to handle this exception, for example creating an empty apple dataset for that file, when this error occurs.

Here I post the chunck of code where I read the file->the group->the dataset. Handling the error, I would like to create anyway an empty `GoldenApples` vector, even when the dataset `apple` doesn't exist.

```
 std::string FileName = "fruit." + std::to_string(cutID) + ".hdf5";

 fruitFile = H5::H5File(FileName, H5F_ACC_RDONLY );

 H5::Group group = fruitFile.openGroup("fruit");
 H5::DataSet dataset = group.openDataSet("apple");
 H5::DataSpace dataspace = dataset.getSpace();
 hsize_t naxes[2];
 dataspace.getSimpleExtentDims(naxes, NULL);

 AppleType = Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(naxes[1], naxes[0]);

 dataset.read(AppleType.data(), H5::PredType::NATIVE_DOUBLE);

 GoldenApples = std::vector<int>(naxes[0], 0.);
 

 //need golden apples, which are in pos (4,i) in matrix AppleType
 for (int i = 0; i < naxes[0]; i++){
   GoldenApples[i] = AppleType(4,i);
   
 }

 fruitFile.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not bound to a particular library, take a look at [HDFql](https://www.hdfql.com) as it's easy to check the existence of an HDF5 dataset with it. Using HDFql in C++, your use-case could be solved as follows:

```
// check if dataset 'apple' exists in HDF5 file 'fruit.h5'
if (HDFql::execute("SHOW DATASET fruit.h5 apple") == HDFql::Success)
{
    std::cout << "Dataset apple exists!" << std::endl;
}
else
{
    std::cout << "Dataset apple does not exist!" << std::endl;
}
```

For additional information about HDFql, please check its [reference manual](https://www.hdfql.com/resources/HDFqlReferenceManual.pdf) as well as some [examples](https://www.hdfql.com/examples).

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a dataset exists by doing `if (group.exists("apple"))`.